# Is Eindhoven a good city for non Dutch?

Tags: netherlands

Is Eindhoven a good city to live for non Dutch young working man and don't speak Dutch for now ?, I mean I will find activities, events, meetups, shopping centers and enable to make new friends .. or it is boring city and hard to meet someone there or doing something new.

Comment: If you're asking about activities for non-Dutch-speakers in Eindhoven, rephrase your question to be about that only. Otherwise it's much too broad.

Answer (score 3):

The question is personal, individual and quite broad.

I know a lot of expats living in Eindhoven or area. Eindhoven is relatively big city and all his inhabitants definitely "survive" there with supermarkets, hospitals, restaurants, cultural live. As well, Netherlands is a quite small country with good transportation, so you're not limited by the Eindhoven area.

Will you able to make friends? It depends on my factors, mostly on your personality and attitude. Dutch known as one of the closest nation to external - whether it is an expat or Dutch. But Nord Brabant province is well known for hospitality.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but you answered on part of my question, I mainly asked about life there (events, meetups, festivals ... ) and about making friends, Is it easy for non Dutch speakers, I know that personality play main role, but is language play main role also or not

Comment: In all cities in NL you will not have problem with English, around 90% of Dutch people freely communicate with it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_in_the_Netherlands)